# Как лучше проверить существуют Children у объекта или нет?

Tags: c#, unity3d, null

```
GameObject instance = (GameObject) GameObject.Instantiate (tempPrefab);
Terrain tempTerrain = instance.GetComponentInChildren<Terrain>() as Terrain;
```

Как лучше проверить существуют `Children` у `GameObject instance`.
Так :

```
if(tempTerrain) {
 ...
}
```

или так :

```
if(tempTerrain!=null) {
 ...
}
```

Может есть другие способы проверки более правильные?

Comment: Если тип "детей" не важен, то можно просто запросить кол-во дочерних объектов у родителя: `if (instance.transform.childCount > 0) {...}`

Comment: @Александр Даниловский А что правильней и почему ? В данной ситуации тип детей важен  должен быть Terrain

Comment: Есть какие-то вопросы по ответу?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Спасибо пока нет , только заметил ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе лучше особо не написать, единственное **но**: у класса может быть переопределен оператор равенства, что конечно вряд ли случится в рамках класса `MonoBehaviour`, но все же.

[Для решения этой проблемы можно использовать оператор `is`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is):

```
if (instance.GetComponent<Terrain>() is Terrain terrain) {
    terrain.enabled = true;
}
```

Бонусом такого подхода является то, что переменная `terrain` будет существовать только в границах `if`'а.